# Can sizeof(std::list<T>) vary for different types of T?

Tags: c++, stl

Can I assume that for any type `T`, the type `std::list<T>` will have a same, constant size? Just to make it clear, I mean the size of the 'main' type itself only, not of the memory allocated by it.

It seems logical to me to assume that the size of `T` itself should only affect the size of list nodes allocated using the allocator.

However, there are two things that might cause the variancy of `sizeof(std::list<T>)` I can think of:

1. A standard C++ library trying to 'optimize' the `std::list` type by putting some of `T` instances into the `std::list<T>` itself. That seems like a bad idea to me, and it probably breaks the 'constant time' requirements put by the standard;
2. A standard C++ having library specializations of `std::list<T>` for some types, with the specializations having different sizes.

I can't think of any uses for (1) or (2) but I may be wrong.

What I'm thinking of achieving is using a fixed-size slice allocator for a template class using`std::list<T>` inside.

---

As a note: this is about variance for different types of `T`, and *not* for different allocators. I will have an explicit control of all instantiations, and they all will use the `std::allocator`.

Comment: Interesting, +1. I'm pretty sure, the standard does not guarantee the same size, but still +1 and just a comment :)

Comment: I thought of this thinking about `vector` rather than `list`, but it may contain a `T*`, and not all pointers are the same size... Ok I'm not entirely sure how you'ld create a container of member functions, but ...

Comment: @BoBTFish - All pointers are the same size.

Comment: @KirilKirov: No, that's not true.

Comment: @KirilKirov: Not necessarily; there are platforms where different pointer types have different sizes. C++ only requires that they can all be convertible to `void*` or `(u)intptr_t` and back, not that they are all the same size.

Comment: @Jon - example? And I'm talking about: the same size, independent from the TYPE, NOT the platform.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - wow o.O Example for such platform? I thought, this is guaranteed by the standard..

Comment: @KirilKirov Try it with member function pointers.

Comment: @KirilKirov: [Example](http://ideone.com/UtljD). Pointers to member functions cannot be as small as pointers to free functions, think about it.

Comment: @KirilKirov, Mike and Jon are right. Example is: pointer to member function. Even on conventional platform its sizeof will return different than sizeof(int*)

Comment: Wow, thanks all, I'm really shocked! @MikeSeymour - sorry for the spam.

Comment: @KirilKirov: The [PDP-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10) required `char*` to be larger than `int*`, since it would need to encode both a word address, and the byte offset within the 36-bit word. This is a consequence of adding byte addressing to an architecture that previously only supported word addressing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, it can.

The standard does not precise any guarantee on the size of a `list<T>` object as far as I am aware. Still, there are other guarantees.

---

Let us debunk some things:

> A standard C++ library trying to 'optimize' the `std::list` type by putting some of `T` instances into the `std::list<T>` itself. That seems like a bad idea to me, and it probably breaks the 'constant time' requirements put by the standard;

It does not break the 'constant time' requirement in any way as long as this number is bounded since O(5) is O(1). However, during a `splice` operations, the nodes should move from one list to another *without moving in memory*. Thus local storage is prohibited.

> A standard C++ having library specializations of `std::list<T>` for some types, with the specializations having different sizes.

Since we already excluded the possibility of local storage, it is hard to imagine any other variations of the base `std::list<T>` type *by itself*.

---

And let us worry about what matters:

The memory allocated by a `std::list<T>` is provided by its second template argument: the allocator. Most allocators (including `std::allocator<T>` which is the default) use a simple pointer type: `T*`... however an allocator should feel free to change this type.

Therefore, by changing the `allocator` parameter (and more precisely, its pointer type), one will naturally change the size of the `std::list` container in all the implementations I have seen of it.

*Note that the allocator itself could be specialized for some types, however with the rebind magic it's a bit more difficult to achieve.*

Comment: +1 for thinking specifically about how the allocator could affect the footprint. Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 23 of the C++11 standard (Containers) does not say anything about their sizes, so technically you cannot assume that the size will be constant. Implementors could (in theory) specialize some container for a specific primitive in a way that affects its footprint.

In practice, you could use a static assertion that `sizeof(list<T>) == sizeof(list<int>)` and use `sizeof(list<int>)` as the "fixed" size. Worst thing that can happen is a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed-size slice allocator for class using `std::list<T>` makes little sense unless you also use a fixed-size slice allocator for the list itself there will probably be many more allocations for the list items than of the list headers.

Now you certainly can provide your own fixed-size slice allocator to the lists using their second template argument, the allocator. However there is a twist: You don't know how big the slice should be. A `list<T>` accepts `allocator<T>`, but what it really needs is `allocator<U>` where U is a structure containing the prev/next pointers and T. To get it it calls method `rebind`, that has signature `template <typename T> template <typename T> allocator<U> allocator<T>::rebind<U>()`.

Since I actually needed to do that once, what I did was to create an object, that holds collection of allocators for several slice sizes. The allocator itself than held a shared pointer to this and a shared pointer to the allocator for size of it's argument. And on rebind I pulled appropriate allocator from the collection, or created one if it didn't exist. If you do this, it will as a side-effect solve allocation of the lists, because if there is more than one size, it will create separate pool for each. And it's not like there would be many different sizes, because the objects won't be big.

Comment: The list is used inside the slice allocator itself, and thus it has to be allocated directly. However, the `std::list<T>` itself should be small enough to benefit from using slice allocator.